# Bluetooth HDP implementation error in Android ICS

Tags: android-ndk, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to test one app with **Bluetooth HDP** in a Sony Xperis Ice Cream Sandwitch phone.
I have implemented the BluetoothHDPService class and one test activity class.
I am interfacing with a Blood Pressure device made by Omron which supports **IEEE 11073** protocol.To implement IEEE 11073 I am using antidote,an open source stack which implements IEEE 11073 using **android NDK** feature.I am running one service HealthService which interacts with both the BluetoothHDPService and antidote.

In the device,I am getting the following error.

```
09-04 17:08:12.571 W/antidote( 3778): Starting Transcoding plugin...
09-04 17:08:12.582 D/libEGL  ( 3800): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-04 17:08:12.582 W/HSSHDP  ( 3778): onServiceConnected to profile: 3
09-04 17:08:12.582 W/HSSHDP  ( 3778): BluetoothHDPService is running.
09-04 17:08:12.582 W/HSS     ( 3778): HDP service connected
09-04 17:08:12.582 W/HSSHDP  ( 3778): Activity client registered
09-04 17:08:12.592 D/libEGL  ( 3800): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
09-04 17:08:12.592 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793):
registerSinkHealthApplicationNative:  D-Bus error:  
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod (Method "CreateApplication" with signature   
"a{sv}" on interface "org.bluez.HealthManager" doesn't exist
09-04 17:08:12.592 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793): )
09-04 17:08:12.602 W/HSS     ( 3778): HDP Registered
09-04 17:08:12.602 D/libEGL  ( 3800): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
09-04 17:08:12.602 D/libEGL  ( 3800): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
09-04 17:08:12.602 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793): 
registerSinkHealthApplicationNative: D-Bus error:     
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod (Method "CreateApplication" with signature   
"a{sv}" on interface "org.bluez.HealthManager" doesn't exist
09-04 17:08:12.602 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793): )
09-04 17:08:12.602 W/HSS     ( 3778): HDP Registered
09-04 17:08:12.612 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793):
registerSinkHealthApplicationNative: D-Bus error:   
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod (Method "CreateApplication" with signature  
"a{sv}" on interface "org.bluez.HealthManager" doesn't exist
09-04 17:08:12.612 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793): )
09-04 17:08:12.612 W/HSS     ( 3778): HDP Registered
09-04 17:08:12.612 **E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793):   
registerSinkHealthApplicationNative:   D-Bus error:    
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod (Method "CreateApplication" with signature    
"a{sv}" on interface "org.bluez.HealthManager" doesn't exist**
09-04 17:08:12.612 E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793): )
09-04 17:08:12.612 W/HSS     ( 3778): HDP Registered
09-04 17:08:12.622 I/libblt_hw( 1426): Library closed (handle = 0, fd = 25)
09-04 17:08:12.622 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3800): Enabling debug mode 0
09-04 17:08:12.632 W/HST     ( 3800): Service connection established
09-04 17:08:12.632 W/HST     ( 3800): Configuring...
09-04 17:08:12.632 W/HSS     ( 3778): ConfigurePassive
09-04 17:08:12.632 W/HSS     ( 3778): Configured agent    
com.signove.health.service.HealthAgentAPI$Stub$Proxy@41579f38
09-04 17:08:12.702 I/ActivityManager( 1793): Displayed    
com.signove.health.servicetest/.HealthServiceTestActivity: +501ms
09-04 17:08:12.912 I/libblt_hw( 1426): Library closed (handle = 2, fd = 32)
09-04 17:08:15.184 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
09-04 17:08:15.184 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c   
4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
09-04 17:08:15.184 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
09-04 17:08:15.184 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): nl80211: survey data missing!
09-04 17:08:15.364 D/ADM     ( 1450):    devset:282    STATUS Close device 'Speaker'
09-04 17:08:16.816 D/dalvikvm( 3169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1766K, 17% free   
11169K/13411K, paused 4ms+4ms
09-04 17:08:17.036 D/dalvikvm( 1793): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1815K, 28% free 
14916K/20579K, paused 9ms+6ms
09-04 17:08:18.197 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
09-04 17:08:18.197 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 
4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
09-04 17:08:18.197 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
09-04 17:08:18.197 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): nl80211: survey data missing!
09-04 17:08:21.200 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
09-04 17:08:21.200 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c  
4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
09-04 17:08:21.200 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
09-04 17:08:21.200 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): nl80211: survey data missing!
09-04 17:08:23.993 D/BluetoothEventLoop( 1793): Device property changed:  
00:22:58:35:C2:5F property: Connected value: true
09-04 17:08:24.203 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
09-04 17:08:24.203 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c  
4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
09-04 17:08:24.203 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
09-04 17:08:24.203 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): nl80211: survey data missing!
09-04 17:08:27.116 D/dalvikvm( 3169): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1766K, 17% free   
11206K/13411K, paused 3ms+3ms
09-04 17:08:27.206 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
09-04 17:08:27.206 E/wpa_supplicant( 1879):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 
4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
09-04 17:08:27.206 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
09-04 17:08:27.206 D/wpa_supplicant( 1879): nl80211: survey data missing!
09-04 17:08:27.216 D/dalvikvm( 2243): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1668K, 12% free 
14024K/15843K, paused 4ms+6ms

09-04 17:08:29.028 D/BluetoothEventLoop( 1793): Device property changed:  
00:22:58:35:C2:5F property: Connected value: false
09-04 17:08:29.628 D/SurfaceFlinger( 1426): screenshot: sw=180, sh=320, minZ=0,  
maxZ=21010
09-04 17:08:29.718 I/libblt_hw( 1426): Library opened (handle = 0, fd = 25)
09-04 17:08:29.808 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3800): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-04 17:08:29.828 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3800): Flushing caches (mode 1)
09-04 17:08:29.828 W/HST     ( 3800): Unconfiguring...
09-04 17:08:29.828 I/ActivityManager( 1793): No longer want com.android.calendar (pid  
3281): hidden #16
09-04 17:08:29.838 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3778): Flushing caches (mode 1)
09-04 17:08:29.838 W/HSS     ( 3778): Unconfigure
09-04 17:08:29.838 W/HSS     ( 3778): Unconfigured agent       
com.signove.health.service.HealthAgentAPI$Stub$Proxy@4157a4c8
09-04 17:08:29.838 W/HST     ( 3800): Activity destroyed
09-04 17:08:30.029 I/libblt_hw( 1426): Library closed (handle = 5, fd = 29)
```

Can anyone please help me regarding

```
E/BluetoothService.cpp( 1793):registerSinkHealthApplicationNative:   D-Bus error:    
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod (Method "CreateApplication" with signature    
"a{sv}" on interface "org.bluez.HealthManager" doesn't exist
```

this error?? Where can I find this **BluetoothService.cpp** file in my android code??
What should be the right approach to implement the **org.bluez.HealthManager** in the code?

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones have HDP disabled on Bluetooth stack, even though the Android-level API is there. I think it is the case.

The error message is very low-level, tells that BlueZ does not recognize this method call. Since the CreateApplication method works even in absence of paired HDP devices, I think that BlueZ running in your phone simply does not support HDP.